# Reading a AppKey value from web.config in clientside js SPA

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-config, durandal

I have Durandal SPA which uses `url.config.js` file among different views. Bunch of urls to services are stored there.

Code for clarity:

```
define([], function () { 
    var serviceBaseUrl = 'http://localhost/Service/api/';
    var portalPortalUrl = 'http://localhost/Portal';
});
```

And whenever I need to deploy my app, or run it with different IIS settings, I need to manually change this urls in code.

What I want:

To store them in `Web.config` file so I can have different configuration for debug and release modes.

I am using MVC 5 Razor views only for rendering bundles and initial content, all client side logic placed in `Durandal` folder.

I have only found solutions using `ASP.NET ConfigurationManager` like so:

```
 function ReadConfigurationSettings()
 {
     var k = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["var1"].ToString() %>'
     alert(k);
 }
```

Or, for Razor:

```
@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"]
```

It's cool, but not my way.
Maybe it's possible to auto generate my `urls.config.js` file based on `Web.config` keys?
Thank you in advance.

If needed, here is my project structure:

```
- App //Durandal SPA 
- Controllers 
- Views //Only render initial view 
- Web.config
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**JavaScriptResult**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.javascriptresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

> Sends JavaScript content to the response.

*Code*, Controller Action method

```
public JavaScriptResult Config()
{
    var script = string.Format(@"var configServiceBaseUrl = {0};", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["var1"]);
    return JavaScript(script);
}
```

In the page header(I would load the file first), You can define:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Action("Config", "Controller")'></script>
```

Now `configServiceBaseUrl` is Global JavaScript variable which you can use anywhere.

So you can use `configServiceBaseUrl` in `url.config.js` like

```
define([], function () { 
    var serviceBaseUrl = configServiceBaseUrl;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [satpal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533/satpal), for **SPA** application such as **angular js**

For SPA's, such as angular you can use below code in your index.html as

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src='/Controller/config'></script>
```